# Nice puzzle: Creating a binary word using weights and scales

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

You are given $N$ weights where for each $i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$, the $i$-th weight weighs $i$ pounds. You are given an $N$-binary-word that's formed by $L$'s and $R$'s and scales. You need to provide an algorithm of $N$ steps, which in each step puts a weight on one of the scales (the left or the right one), and that in the $i$-th step the scales will lean left if the $i$-th letter in the word is $L$ and will lean right if it's $R$.

For example: if $N=3$ and the word is $LLR$ then the algorithm should say:

1. Put $2$ on the left scale (since $2>0$, the scales will lean to the left).
2. Put $1$ on the right scale (since $2>1$, the scales will still lean to the left).
3. Put $3$ on the right scale (since $2<1+3$, the scales will lean to the right).

Comment: if the scale is balanced, does it count either as L or R? In your example, it happens at the third step

Comment: @mau, I don't think so. After the 3rd step, 2 is on the left, $1+3=4$ is on the right.

Comment: @mau if the scale is balanced it doesn't count to either L or R.

Comment: ok, I read it wrongly, and I thought that the weights should be added in their order. Sorry.